# htaccess conditional redirect to a 404 page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

applied a RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/basic/?$ /basic.php?player=$2&platform=$1 [NC]
```

for converting

```
/basic.php?player=$2&platform=$1
```

URL to pretty

```
/$1/$2/basic
```

then applied

```
RewriteRule ^pc/([^/]*)/?$ /pc/$1/basic/ [NC,R=301]
```

for redirecting this

```
/$1/$2
```

to this

```
/$1/$2/basic
```

the problem is when entering only this

```
/$1
```

it shows 404 not found error page but when entering

```
/$1/
```

it redirects to

```
/$1/basic/basic
```

Is there any way to display a 404 Not Found error page instead

here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

#redirect -- /platform/player/ => /platform/player/basic
RewriteRule ^pc/([^/]*)/?$ /pc/$1/basic/ [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^ps3/([^/]*)/?$ /ps3/$1/basic/ [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^ps4/([^/]*)/?$ /ps4/$1/basic/ [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^xbox/([^/]*)/?$ /xbox/$1/basic/ [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^xone/([^/]*)/?$ /xone/$1/basic/ [NC,R=301]

#format -- /platform/player/page
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/basic/?$ /basic.php?player=$2&platform=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/weapons/?$ /weapons.php?player=$2&platform=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/vehicles/?$ /vehicles.php?player=$2&platform=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/awards/?$ /awards.php?player=$2&platform=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/kititems/?$ /kititems.php?player=$2&platform=$1 [NC]

ErrorDocument 400 /errordoc/error.php?error=400
ErrorDocument 401 /errordoc/error.php?error=401
ErrorDocument 403 /errordoc/error.php?error=403
ErrorDocument 404 /errordoc/error.php?error=404
ErrorDocument 500 /errordoc/error.php?error=500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/$1/` is matching the first

```
RewriteRule ^pc/([^/]*)/?$ /pc/$1/basic/ [NC,R=301]
```

rule because you have optional `*` and `/?` patterns, so `/pc/` will match that regex. Make those fields *required* fields instead:

```
#redirect -- /platform/player/ => /platform/player/basic
RewriteRule ^pc/([^/]+)/?$ /pc/$1/basic/ [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^ps3/([^/]+)/?$ /ps3/$1/basic/ [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^ps4/([^/]+)/?$ /ps4/$1/basic/ [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^xbox/([^/]+)/?$ /xbox/$1/basic/ [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^xone/([^/]+)/?$ /xone/$1/basic/ [NC,R=301]
```

by changing the `*` to a `+`.